# check which or-statement is used in mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb query to find all accounts where the user is owner or collaborator. This is my query:

```
const selectAccounts = await account
    .find({
        $or: [
            { owner: { $eq: credentials } },
            { collaborators: { $in: [credentials] } },
        ],
    })
    .select("accountId")
    .exec();
```

This query works as expected, but I want to know if there is an option to add to the results if the returning account ID is an owner or a collaborator.

Comment: something like [this?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gHbQx9jcY8U)

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, you could either split it into two queries, getting a list of the accounts the user is an owner of and a list of the accounts the user is a collaborator of separately.
Note: Your queries can be simplified, it is not necessary to use $in to find a document with an array containing a specific value, it is for finding a value matching one of many values. See this for details on querying arrays: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/

You can also run the queries in parallel to reduce run time : )

```
let ownedAccountsPromise = accounts
  .find({ owner: credentials })
  .select("accountId");

let collaboratorAccountsPromise = accounts
  .find({ collaborators: credentials })
  .select("accountId");

const [ownedAccounts, collaboratorAccounts] = await Promise.all([ownedAccountsPromise, collaboratorAccountsPromise]);
```

Or you could include the `owner` in the fields selected and check after.

```
const taggedAccounts = selectAccounts.map(account => ({
  accountId: account.accountId,
  isOwner: account.owner === credentials
}));
```